# Nodejs send waterfall requests

Tags: node.js, async-await, async.js, waterfall

I have dynamic array with foldername and creating a zip using **zipFolder**
I am facing issues as the library is async i.e

```
zipFolder(source,dest,callback)
```

Because its a async call it take times and I want to block the next request unless the first one reponse is true,

```
function (req, res)
     var folder = ['N','PP','Y'];//dynamic just an example

        for( var i = 0 ; i < folder.length ; i++) {
            var source = path.join(basePath,'/download/'+folder[i]);
            var dest =   path.join(basePath,'/createZip/'+folder[i]+'.zip');
            console.log('sending',folders[i])


            //this is async
            zipFolder(source,dest, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log('oh no!', err);
                } else {
                    console.log('EXCELLENT');//want to send the second,third,fourth if success
                }
            });
        }
```

Summary:
output should be like this:

**sending file 1** if success/response  **sending file 2** if success/response

want something like waterfall wait for callback reponse to send the second file

plus I want a method to know the **done call back** so I can send back the reponse

Comment: I would advice using Promise with `async` `await`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use each as like:

```
var each = require('async-each-series')
      var folder = ['N','PP','Y'];


       each(folder, function(items,callback){
        //insert each items to db in async way
           var source = path.join(basePath,'/download/'+items);
           var dest =   path.join(basePath,'/createZip/'+items+'.zip');
           zipFolder(source,dest, function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log('oh no!', err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(items,'inserted')
                        callback()
                    }
                });

    },function(err){
           if(err) console.log('error occured')
        console.log('all items uploaded');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with async `waterfall` method

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall

> Runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing their
>   results to the next in the array. However, if any of the tasks pass an
>   error to their own callback, the next function is not executed, and
>   the main callback is immediately called with the error

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

**UPDATE**

in your usecase `eachSeries` is more applicable.

```
 var folder = ['N','PP','Y'];


      async.eachSeries(folder, function(item,callback){
            var source = path.join(basePath,'/download/'+item);
            var dest =   path.join(basePath,'/createZip/'+item+'.zip');

            zipFolder(source,dest, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log('oh no!', err);
                    callback();
                } else {
                    console.log('EXCELLENT');//want to send the second,third,fourth if success
                    callback();
                }
            });

     },function(){
         console.log('all items uploaded');
    });    .
```

Comment: how to handle the array provided above

Comment: @OsheenFatimah modified based on your requirement